# Java 8 rewriting a complex for loop using streams

Tags: java, for-loop, java-8, java-stream

Is it possible to rewrite a complicated for loop like this just using java 8 streams? Anything I come up with seems more bloated, then just leaving the code as is below with a normal for loop.

```
public static  boolean isBalanced(String text) {
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++ ) {
        if (text.charAt(i) == ')') {
            count--;
        } else if (text.charAt(i) == '(') {
            count++;
        }
        if (count < 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return count == 0;
}
```

Using Streams

```
public static boolean isBalanced2(String text) {
    AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(0);

    text.chars()
        .forEachOrdered(x -> {
             if (x == ')') {
                 count.getAndDecrement();
             } else if (x == '(') {
                 count.getAndIncrement();
             }
        });

    return count.get() == 0;
}
```

It works ok but it iterates through the whole string, when sometimes that might be wasted computation for example in the case of the string  ")......"

It doesn't seem possible to exit the stream as soon as count is < 0 ?
(And I dont want to throw an exception!)

Thanks

Comment: I'd use `for (char c : test.toCharArray()) {` (or equivalent with code points).

Comment: u could give people time to response...

Comment: public static boolean isBalanced2(String text) {
        AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(0);

        text.chars().
                forEachOrdered(x -> {
                    if (x == ')') {
                        count.getAndDecrement();
                    } else if (x == '(') {
                        count.getAndIncrement();
                    }
                });

        return count.get() == 0;
    }

It works fine just that it iterates through the whole string, when sometimes it might be wasted computation for example in the case of the string  ")......"

Comment: i will suggest to explain the use case also, i mean what do you need exactly? and why are you returning `if (count < 0)` and `return count == 0;` better to explain what do you want @Pat

Comment: Doesn't the `Stream` approach in this post fail for a `String` like `)(`? The early return is not just performance tuning, but essentially for the algorithm. Order of braces is important.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, Id like to mention code which involves side-effects typically does not work well with streams for that reason alone I'd suggest proceeding with the imperative approach as:

1. the code short circuits
2. it's readable as written

As for:

> It works ok but it iterates through the whole string, when sometimes
>   that might be wasted computation for example in the case of the string

*Any attempt to short-circuit the stream solution you've shown will involve [side-effects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html)* and this, in general, is discouraged.

> Side-effects in behavioral parameters to stream operations are, in
>   general, discouraged, as they can often lead to unwitting violations
>   of the statelessness requirement, as well as other thread-safety
>   hazards. If the behavioral parameters do have side-effects, unless
>   explicitly stated, there are no guarantees as to the visibility of
>   those side-effects to other threads, nor are there any guarantees that
>   different operations on the "same" element within the same stream
>   pipeline are executed in the same thread.

The conclusion is that streams are not always the solution to all problems rather for specific cases and this case is definitely not stream friendly.

Comment: I agree that this is not a stream friendly task, but it [can be done](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53918521/5221149) without using side-effects, but without short-circuiting.

Comment: @Andreas sure, but I said "Any attempt to **short-circuit** the stream solution you've shown will involve side-effects and this, in general, is discouraged."

Comment: True, but the short-circuiting only happens for unbalanced `)`, not for unbalanced `(`, so the short-circuiting is more of a nice boost, not a requirement. As such, a stream solution that doesn't short-circuit may be acceptable, as long as the result is correct.

Comment: @Andreas Right, I was just trying to answer the _"It works ok but it iterates through the whole string, when sometimes that might be wasted computation for example in the case of the string...."_ part of the post which sounds like they still want to maintain short-circuiting but yes I agree with you _"a stream solution that doesn't short-circuit **may** be acceptable, as long as the result is correct."_

Answer (score 2):

You should not.

Lambda and `Stream` are not replacement for all complicated `for` loop. While you may use a `Stream` as you've done, this does not means it is better for the eye (what is easier to understand?) and for performance (you surely lost something due to the `AtomicInteger` vs `int` based operation but you could probably use a `int[]` array instead).

- You can't exit the loop as soon as possible, unless you use exception, but you can narrow your test a little (and you should bench it). You could probably think of using `filter` after `map` operation but that won't make it easier to read.
- You should probably stick to [pure function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function), eg: you should probably not have a side effect (on the `AtomicInteger`).

Answer (score 2):

The following code will do what you want, and is smaller than your original code, but it's convoluted and always processes all characters, i.e. doesn't stop early if unbalanced `)` is detected.

However, unlike some other answers here, it doesn't violate the stream rules by maintaining state outside the stream.

```
private static boolean isBalanced(String text) {
    return 0 == text.chars()
            .reduce(0, (n, c) -> n < 0 ? n : c == '(' ? n + 1 : c == ')' ? n - 1 : n);
}
```

The logic is as follows:

- Keep a running total representing the nesting level, i.e. increment the value when `(` is found and decrement the value when `)` is found.
- If the total goes below 0, stop updating it, i.e. when an unbalanced `)` is found, keep final total at -1.

The result of the `reduce` operation is then:

- **`0`**: All `(` have balanced `)`
- **`-1`**: Found unbalanced `)`
- **`>0`**: Found unbalanced `(`

Long version of the same code, using `if` statements instead of conditional ternary operator.

```
private static boolean isBalanced(String text) {
    int finalLevel = text.chars().reduce(0, (lvl, ch) -> {
        if (lvl < 0)
            return lvl; // Keep result of -1 for unbalanced ')'
        if (ch == '(')
            return lvl + 1;
        if (ch == ')')
            return lvl - 1;
        return lvl;
    });
    return (finalLevel == 0);
}
```

Comment: Note that the reduction function described here isn't associative. The scenario in this answer will work, but it relies on sequential, left-to-right execution. If the reduction function were modified or repurposed, particularly if it were run in parallel, it won't give the correct result.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a similar solution to yours using Java 8.

First map `'('`, `')'` and other characters to `1`, `-1` and `0` respectively. Then compute a cumulative sum and check that each partial sum `ps >= 0` and the final sum `s == 0`. By using `allMatch` for the partial sum checking the process is short-circuiting.

```
public static boolean isBalanced(String text) {
    AtomicInteger s = new AtomicInteger();
    return text.chars()
            .map(ch -> (ch == '(') ? 1 : (ch == ')') ? -1 : 0)
            .map(s::addAndGet)
            .allMatch(ps -> ps >= 0) && s.get() == 0;
}
```

Here is a solution that supports multiple different parentheses (requires some `IntStack` implementation):

```
IntStack stack = ...;
return text.chars()
        .map("(){}[]"::indexOf)
        .filter(i -> i >= 0)
        .allMatch(i -> {
            int form = i / 2; // 0 = (), 1 = {}, 2 = []
            int side = i % 2; // 0 = left, 1 = right
            if (side == 0) {
                stack.push(form);
                return true;
            } else {
                return stack.size() != 0 && stack.pop() == form;
            }
        }) && stack.size() == 0;
```

Comment: This is the best answer I can see. OP, Please accept this answer.

Comment: @KunalPuri:  This is shoehorning streams into a purpose which doesn't make them easy to maintain, doesn't let them leverage one of the principle strengths of streams, and would be code that would be tougher to maintain in the long haul.  Gonna forcefully disagree with you thinking that this is the "best" answer.

Comment: @Makoto By best answer, I wanted to say is that this is the best answer using stream. I completely agree with you.

Comment: @Makoto One more thing. I feel even the count based method is not that much maintainable. When different possible parentheses will come like curly braces, square braces etc., the solution will struggle. Instead, I feel this should be done using stack and map.

Comment: @KunalPuri Added another solution that uses a stack to support different parentheses.

Comment: @Bubletan I can only give +1 once :) For me, this is the best answer using stream.

Answer (score 0):

Streams *do* have the concept of early termination, but only if the terminal operation actually supports it.

From the operation you describe, `forEachOrdered` is going to iterate over *each* element in the stream and it does not have the ability to break early.  Remember:  **streams *could* be infinite**, so breaking the stream early while ordering over each one could be seen as a runtime error.

In essence, I'd actually encourage you to stick with the loop variant over the stream variant, since the loop variant gives you the ability to terminate early.  What you have written for the stream variant is actually reasonable, given what constraints it has to deal with.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
You answered my question - so sometimes we are better off just using a normal loop instead of forcing ourselves to use streams.

Answer (score 0):

You can get early termination of a stream evaluation from one of the terminal operations that supports it.  These turn out to be comparatively few, but if you're willing to tolerate some minor abuse, and you're using Java 9 or later, then you can use `takeWhile()` to perform early termination pretty universally.  The trick (and also the abuse) is to use a state-retaining predicate.  For example:

```
public static boolean isBalanced(String text) {
    final int[] state = new int[0];

    text.chars().takeWhile(c -> {
        if (c == '(') state[0]++; if (c == ')') state[0]--; return state[0] >= 0; 
    });

    return state[0] == 0;
}
```

This is very closely analogous to your original loop.